# Does it matter how you order your filtergraph in ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I recently created an ffmpeg script that takes two groups of three videos each, runs them together in their groups first, then vertically stacks them, while keeping audio for the first group only.

The flow of the filtergraph is:

1. `concat` filter - Run inputs 1 through 3 together including audio
2. `scale` filter - Downsize above concatenation
3. `concat` filter - Run inputs 4 through 6 together excluding audio
4. `scale` filter - Downsize above concatenation
5. `vstack` filter - Vertically stack video output from steps 2 and 4.
6. Map video from step five and audio from step 1.

It works and I'm happy with the results. I haven't experimented, but I wonder if I reordered the filters would it make any performance difference, like less memory or CPU, or even render faster. If I did the following, would it help?:

1. `vstack` filter - Vertically stack inputs 1 and 4, keeping audio from only 1.
2. `vstack` filter - Vertically stack inputs 2 and 5, keeping audio from only 2.
3. `vstack` filter - Vertically stack inputs 3 and 6, keeping audio from only 3.
4. `concat` filter - Run video output from steps 1 through 3 together.
5. `scale` filter - Downsize above concatentation
6. Map video and audio from step 4.

Are there any circumstances where we should expect a different ordering of filters to affect performance?

---

Here is my exact filter graph:

```
-filter_complex "\
[0:v][0:a][1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[spvid][a];\
[spvid]scale=640:-1,setsar=1[top];\
[3:v][4:v][5:v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[slvid];\
[slvid]scale=640:-1,setsar=1[bottom];\
[top][bottom]vstack=inputs=2[outv]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[a]"
```

Comment: Possibly; share your current filtergraph.

Comment: @Gyan I added the filtergraph I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it matters how the filtergraph is ordered. A filtergraph with operations which involve fewer computations or memory operations will be faster.

Video filters which change the resolution or pixel format or any action which cannot modify the frame in-place, need to generate a new frame and compute new pixel values, and so will take more time. Filters like concat which take in frames from multiple sources and simply alter timestamps will take less time. As a rule of thumb, perform such operations in parallel, and serialize more expensive ops, however a specific filtergraph will have to be analyzed in order to determine whether this holds.

I tested your current filtergraph versus the proposed one, and the current one was ~10% faster across 3 trials. I suspect because parallel vstacks may delay feeding frames to the concat filter.

Comment: This is interesting. Are you saying that if filters can run concurrently then they do? - By the logic you give, to improve performance on my original command, I should vstack before I scale. That would be less filters overall.

Comment: I did it that way because I figured vstack would have less trouble if the parts were scaled down first.

Comment: Parallel here refers to logical sequencing, not runtime concurrency, although that does happen as filters can run in separate threads. vstack<->scale performance will depend on original resolution and post-scale resolution; available cores/memory..etc